# Zend Framework 2: Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex optional value

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a controller and action which take a customer name and then do a search on the database to match the customer. Some customers may have a middle name, and some don't.

I have the following two routes for this:

```
        'full-name' => array(
            'type' => 'regex',
            'options' => array(
                'regex' => '/(?<title>Mr|Miss|Mrs|Ms)/(?<firstname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<middlename>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<lastname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Customers',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
                'spec'  => '/%firstname%/%middlename%/%lastname%'
            )
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'type' => 'regex',
            'options' => array(
                'regex' => '/(?<title>Mr|Miss|Mrs|Ms)(?<firstname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<lastname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
                'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Customers',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                ),
                'spec'  => '/%firstname%/%lastname%'
            )
        ),
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to combine them both into one regex rule, but I couldn't find anything that would work for the middle name. I tried a few things like:

```
(?<middlename>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]?)
(?<middlename>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+|^$)
```

But then it complained that there wasn't a matched routed when I tried it without the middle name.
Obviously, I can leave it as it is since it works, but it would be nice if it was possible to combine both routes into one.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

EDIT:
I originally simplified the code a bit compared to what I actually need, but this led to solutions that wouldn't answer my question about optional value in regex. I have changed the code to reflect my why I can't have segment route.

For reference, this was my initial code:

```
        'full-name' => array(
            'type' => 'regex',
            'options' => array(
                'regex' => '/Customer/(?<firstname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<middlename>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<lastname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Customers',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
                'spec'  => '/%firstname%/%middlename%/%lastname%'
            )
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'type' => 'regex',
            'options' => array(
                'regex' => '/Customer/(?<firstname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<lastname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
                'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Customers',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                ),
                'spec'  => '/%firstname%/%lastname%'
            )
        ),
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the `Regex` route class. I know this can be done with a `Segment` route.

```
'name' => array(
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/[:title[/]]:firstname[/:middlename]/:lastname',
        'constraints' => array(
            'title' => 'Mr|Miss|Mrs|Ms',
            'firstname' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
            'middlename' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
            'lastname' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Customers',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

**EDIT:** Updated the answer to reflect the comments.

Comment: Thank you, This is a very good answer, unfortunately I misled with my original code since I don't actually have the "Customer" segment in the URL, but was rather trying to simplify the code for the sake of the question.
In the case of my updated code, if I wanted to do that with a segment route I would have to write four different segment routes, each for every title, which is why I went with regex.


However, this answer would be perfect if I did have the "Customer" segment.

Comment: @user1510297 You could try - Route: /[:title[/]]:firstname[/:middlename]/:lastname and constraint for title of 'Mr|Miss|Mrs|Ms'. If this works I would suggest testing assembling URLs as well as just routing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve this in the controller when you get the parameters from the matched route:

```
'full-name' => array(
    'type' => 'regex',
    'options' => array(
        // look here how I changed the regex in a way that the last parameter is optional
        'regex' => '/Customer/(?<firstname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(?<middlename>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/*(?<lastname>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Customers',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'lastname'   => false, // add some default value to the optional parameter
        ),
        'spec'  => '/%firstname%/%middlename%/%lastname%'
    )
),
```

Then in the controller...

```
public function userAction()
{
    $firstName = $this->params()->fromRoute('firstname');

    // if lastname === false, we have just two parameters (firstname/lastname)
    if ($this->params()->fromRoute('lastname') === false) {
        $lastName = $this->params()->fromRoute('middlename');
        $middleName = NULL;
    } else {
        // if not, we have the three parameters (firstname/middlename/lastname)
        $lastName = $this->params()->fromRoute('lastname');
        $middleName = $this->params()->fromRoute('middlename');
    }
}
```

Other way to write the controller action (it's actually the same thing):

```
public function userAction()
{
    $firstName = $this->params()->fromRoute('firstname');

    $lastName = $this->params()->fromRoute('lastname') === false ?
        $this->params()->fromRoute('middlename') :
        $this->params()->fromRoute('lastname');

    $middleName = $this->params()->fromRoute('lastname') === false ?
        NULL : $this->params()->fromRoute('middlename');
}
```

This way you can use just one route. I can't thing another way to do it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would work for my original code but I want to know the answer in case I don't have the "Customer" segment in my URL, in which case this would not work anymore.

In addition, I don't really like having the if construct in my controller. I like it better how it works with the segment route where you can say that a parameter is optional.